# XPath: stop collect element on first element matching a criteria

Tags: xpath

I have this kind of XML:

```
<item attribute = "val1"> blabla 1 </item>
<item attribute = "val2"> blabla 11 </item>
<item attribute = "val2"> blabla 12 </item>
<item attribute = "val1"> blabla 2 </item>
<item attribute = "val2"> blabla 21 </item>
```

I would like to collect `item` that contain an `element` with `attribute = val2`.

To do so, I use the XPath expression (in lxml Python library):

```
firstItem.xpath('./following-sibling::item[.//@attribute = "val2"]')
```

where the `firstItem` is an element with `attribute = "val1"`.

So this work find and give me the three `<item attribute = "val2">` but it is not exactly what I'm looking for.

I would like that the request fetches me the two element `<item attribute = "val2">` after the first the first element `<item attribute = "val1">` and stops when it reaches the next `<item attribute = "val1">`. When I run the request on the second `<item attribute = "val1">` it shall gave me the last `<item attribute = "val2">`.
Of course, in my case I can have more than two `<item attribute = "val1">`.

So how to tell in a XPath request to stop to search on the first `<item attribute = "val1">` reached ?

Comment: you can try `./following-sibling::item[@attribute = "val2" and count(preceding-sibling::item[@attribute="val1"]) = 1]`

Comment: @Andersson 

I tried what you proposed. It work fine the first time for the elements `<item attribute = "val2"> blabla 11 </item>`, <item attribute = "val2"> blabla 12 </item>`

But it does not work when I run the expression on the element `<item attribute = "val1"> blabla 2 </item>`. I guess the expression took in count the element `<item attribute = "val1"> blabla 1 </item>`

Comment: For next `item[@attribute = "val1"]` you need to pass `2` instead of `1` to `count(preceding-sibling::item[@attribute="val1"]) = 1` ...

Comment: @Andersson well, it's a bit more complex apparently. I found a solution based on what you propose : `'./following-sibling::item[@attribute = "val2" and count(preceding-sibling::item[@attribute="val1"]) = ' + str(index) + ']'` where the index is the number of `<item attribute = "val1">` before `<item attribute = "val2">` we are looking for. We can simplify to `//item[@attribute = "val2" and count(preceding-sibling::item[@attribute="val1"]) = ' + str(index) + ']'`

For me, this solution work but does not seem to be very elegant ...

Comment: Sorry I misread your previous comment; What i did is exactly what you said ^^